# PIL.Image rote pads image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am loading an image with the PIL library and rotate it based on its exif tags.
The problem is, that the rotations adds an pading for some reason.
The code is like this

```
def getImage(imgName):
    with Image.open(imgName) as image:
        try:
            for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys():
                if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation] == 'Orientation':
                    break
            exif = dict(image._getexif().items())

            if exif[orientation] == 3:
                image = image.rotate(180, expand=True)
            elif exif[orientation] == 6:
                print(np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32).shape) # shape = (3168, 4752, 3)
                image = image.rotate(270, expand=True)
                print(np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32).shape) # shape = (4753, 3169, 3)
            elif exif[orientation] == 8:
                image = image.rotate(90, expand=True)


        except (AttributeError, KeyError, IndexError):
            # cases: image don't have getexif
            pass
        image = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32)

    return image
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?
(Surprisingely this only happens on the server (Linux) I use, and not my laptop (Windows)

On my local mashine I am using Python 3.5.3, Numpy 1.12.1 and PIL 1.1.7

And on the server they run Python 3.5.2, Numpy 1.11.3 and also PIL 1.1.7

Comment: Please add further information about the version of `python`, `PIL` and `numpy` you're using; and please check if setting ` expand=False` solves your problem.

Comment: Using `image.transpose` would probably be better than using `rotate`, since the latter may be lossy (it's designed for non-90 degree rotations).

Comment: @Blckknght Unfortunately this has not the same effect, as the rotate method. Transpose is a morroring operation, I explicitely need the rotation though

Comment: There are arguments you can give to [`transpose`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.transpose) to request a rotation of 90, 180 or 270 degrees.